# How to add Hyperlink in Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

I have a requirement where in i need to print a field called Opportunity ID in VisualForce Page.  This field should be displayed with hyperlink, so that when we click on this field link, we should navigate to that particular Opportunity.  To get this requirement, i used the following one.

```
<apex:page controller="Example2">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection id="one">
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accs}" var="a">
                    <apex:outputlink value="/{!a.Id}">{!a.Name}</apex:outputlink>
                    <apex:column value="{!a.name}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:commandButton value="Click" action="{!main}" reRender="one"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

But, I never any link on any field. Could any one suggest a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the outputlink inside an apex:column tag or else it will not display if inside a pageBlockTable.

Also you need to put the commandbutton inside a pageBlockButtons tag, otherwise it will interfere with the table columns.

```
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:commandButton value="Click" action="{!main}" reRender="one"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockSection id="one">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accs}" var="a">
                <apex:column headerValue="Account hyperlink">
                   <apex:outputlink value="/{!a.Id}">{!a.Name}</apex:outputlink>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column value="{!a.name}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:commandButton value="Click" action="{!main}" reRender="one"/>
    </apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: @ Guy, Its working good. But if i click on the link directly, ITS giving wrong display. its showing perfect output if we use it take a new tab only.
can you give a solution for it?

Comment: The default behavior is to open in current page. Is that not happening?

Comment: yes @Guy, its not opening in current page. its taking URL like `https://c.ap2.visual.force.com/apex/VfpageName`

Comment: the commandbutton might be causing this. Could you try (temporarily) removing it? You could consider putting the commandbutton inside a pageblockbuttons tag.

Comment: If we remove command button, how we can display records of object with out any action?

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly. But if you put the commandbutton inside a pageblockbuttons tag, it will work exactly the same way without interfering with the table/columns.

Comment: Yes Guy, I got it and its working now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Great :-)  I've updated the answer accordingly. Please accept the answer if it worked for you, thanks.